# Checking whether the necessary DOM node is still there in browser before retrying an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

In my firefox extension, I am sending an ajax request. If that fails I will retry the request. But at this time, I need to check whether the DOM node I am going to populate after the request completion is still there in browser(User might have closed the tab or navigated away from this page). If it is not there I have to abort the request.

I know that I can do this by a DOM search.(getElementById or $(element)). But since we have the access to the document(element.ownerDocument), can I check whether the document is still valid? I think this would be more efficient.

Comment: I don't think you have to worry about efficiency here. Unless you prove that there's a bottleneck, either approach will work. This is premature optimization since getElementById is fast enough

Comment: yeah. But I want to know whether I can check the validity of document. Because this will be easier than DOM search even though DOM search is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
if (element.ownerDocument && element.ownerDocument.defaultView)
```

When the tab is closed the document will still be around (you are preventing it from being garbage collected by holding a reference to the element) but it will be detached from a view (`window` object).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.length` property. It will return 0 if the element no longer exists. It's preferred over `.size()` since it doesn't require a function call. From the jQuery docs:

> The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property;
>   however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have
>   the overhead of a function call.